# converting timestamp from descending to new/different ascending value in excel

Tags: sorting, excel, timestamp, formulas, vba

I have the values of the first half of a college basketball game counting down from 20 minutes. I need to match the times that I have with the times on a DVD where the times are different ascending from a value at 40:36 minutes.

The basketball game counts down from 20 minutes (the tip-off) whereas the time on the DVD goes up from 40:36 minutes (the tip-off on the DVD). It would save me hours and hours of work if I could somehow automate this process. I did the below manually. Any ideas?

```
Values I Have = Values I Need: (starting from 40:36 ascending up)

20:00           = 40:36

19:40           = 40:56

19:40           = 40:56

19:11           = 41:25

19:10           = 41:26

18:56           = 41:40

18:40           = 41:56

18:13           = 42:23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=(B1-A5)+B2
```

- B1 = Time in Quarter
- A5 = Game time
- B2 = Start of DVD time (0:40:36)

e.g.:

```
Time in Quarter     0:20:00
Start time on DVD   0:46:36

Game time   DVD time
0:19:40     =(B1-A5)+B2
```

Make sure you have the times are stored in the following format: 12:20:00 AM for 20:00 so that excel can do the time arithmetic correctly. You can format the cells to h:mm:ss if you want.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your help. I got the first cell just how I want it, based on what Luke suggested. Thanks Luke! I think pnuts is right though - I need to anchor the B values to propagate the correct times downward in the column. I'm trying to figure out how to do that now.

Comment: Hey Luke, though that formula works perfectly I'm having trouble formatting the hh:mm:ss properly. Every time I copy the original data into a column, excel auto-formats it to 8:00:00 PM (for 20:00). I mean it shows 20:00, but then when I double click in the cell it shows 8:00:00 PM. Is there any way to propagate 20:00 to show up as 12:20:00 AM instead. I mean I know I could change it to be 0:20:00 and that would fix it, but I'd have to do that manually. Is there a way to automate this? Thanks!

Comment: I guess in simpler terms... If my source file comes with the value as 20:00 how can I convert it to 0:20:00?

Answer (score 1):

Using this formula solved my issues described above.

=LEFT(CONCATENATE("00:",TEXT(A18,"hh:mm:ss")),8)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, amazing. You guys really saved me a lot of work here!

=($B$1-A5)+$B$2 is all I needed!

Using Luke's formula while anchoring the B column values is exactly what I needed.

Guys, I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help. Thank you both!!! :)